# Alternatives to least-Chi-square to fit a straight line,

Tags: linear-model, fitting

as stated in the title I am looking for alternative ways to fit my data to a straight line. My current approach is a least Chi-Square Fitting, but the predicted relative errors for the slope exceed 100%.

In my view there are to reasons for that:

a) I only have five data points to fit.
b) These five data points have very large errors (relative error is about 20%).

To clarify the issue I attached the data at the end of this post.

Do you know of other methods to fit data by a linear function, which are better suited to this ill-posed problem?

Since this is my first post here and especially my first post regarding science ever, I hope that I stated my question correctly. Thank you in advance!

Data (x, y, error of y)
$0.025 \qquad 0.66 \qquad 0.14$
$0.099 \qquad 0.72 \qquad 0.14$
$0.220  \qquad 0.78 \qquad 0.14$
$0.390 \qquad 0.75 \qquad 0.14$
$0.620 \qquad 0.83 \qquad 0.14$

Comment: Hi Christian, welcome to the site. By "leas-Chi-square fit" do you possibly mean [least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares), which is a normal linear regression? An what do you mean by saying that "the predicted relative errors for the slope exceed 100%"? A bit more information what x and y is would be helpful.

Comment: @COOLSerdash The OP may mean fitting by *minimum chi-square*; usually it's used with Poisson or binomial sampling situations but also applies if you know the variance of the observations and assume normality, when it's equivalent to WLS (except all your t's are Z's and all your F's are chi-square).

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for clarifying. I was unaware of this method. Thanks.

Comment: As stated by Glen_b I meant "least squares" with least-Chi-square-fit.

Comment: The variable x corresponds to a momentum squared and the y is an observable. The functional dependence is:  $y(x)=b + m*x$  and I am interested in the slope $m$ of this function.

Comment: @COOLSerdash Exceeding 100% means that the error for the slope computed by these least squares fit is much larger than the slope $m$: $m=.23$ and the error $\delta m=.29$

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me exactly what you want, but if we plot these points (e.g. in `R`)

```
x <- c(0.025, 0.099, 0.22, 0.39, 0.62)
y <- c(0.66, 0.72, 0.78, 0.75, 0.83)

plot(x,y,type = 'p')
```

we can add a least squares fit line

```
abline(lsfit(x,y))
```

which (as least square lines often do) looks pretty good, intuitively.

[image]

Comment: I agree, but as should be clear this is a small dataset. Note that quantile regression (L_1 norm) yields a loosely similar but not identical line.

Comment: Hi @NickCox yes, and other norms would probably be similar lines too, as would smoothing methods. But the questioner seems to think (although it's hard to tell) that the least squares line isn't very good here, so I just wanted to show that it is.

Comment: I agree completely.

Comment: Sorry, that I did not clealy state my point. I would like to extract the slope of the fitted function $y(x)=b+mx$.  Doing this for the given data set with the least squares method I obtain something like: $m=0.23$ with an error of $\delta m=0.29$. My problem is that the error is larger than the result. Is there another method to fit a straight line, which maybe gives smaller errors?

Comment: @PeterFlom Sorry, I realized too late that I should mention you. Please see the post above.